# How to manage assets from Razor class libraries in a Multi Hosted Blazor Apps environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, msbuild, blazor-webassembly

When hosting multiple Blazor apps under the same Razor Pages App, we use this setting to separate static assets from the respective Apps:

**App1.csproj**:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StaticWebAssetBasePath>app1</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**App2.csproj**:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StaticWebAssetBasePath>app2</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But these settings don't affect assets from Razor Class Libraries. If for example, I am using  Blazorise Razor Library in **App1**, `_content/Blazorise/blazorise.css` will still be accessible from the root `/`, not from `/app1/`, and with `<base href="/app1/" />` in my **App1.cshtml**, loading `_content/Blazorise/blazorise.css` always fail.

Is there a way to also save the Razor Class Libraries assets so they can be accessible from `/app1/` and not the root `/`.

I guess it should be some non-trivial MSBuild code, I have no idea how to do it.